# Set IE Homepage with c# and disable changing it?

Tags: internet-explorer, add-in, toolbar

One of our customers requested us to develop an IE ToolBar which sets clients homepage to their company web site and track it via registry. We would like to track users homepage if it's still set to company's web site.

Questions:

1. I can set it via registry but we also want to disable for user to change it (disabling the ie homepage textbox). How can we do it?
2. Is there any way to track the home page dynamically like FileSystemWatcher?

Thanks!

**To everyone who thinks we' re trying to do an illegal think: this is a 30 days campaign; do not think that we're doing an illegal thing. We will not do it automatically without users approval, user will install it manually after subscription, accepting the eula of the campaign and he/she will be istructed about what will happens if he/she installs the add-in.**

Comment: Why do people down-vote this? If you think this is a bad practice, explain it in an answer/comment. There's nothing wrong with the *question*.

Comment: I heard there was a German man who found a victim who agreed to submit to being cannibalized.  I don't think the fact the guy was willing makes it any more palatable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very malware-like to me. Why would you impede users' freedoms? You're also implying that the user is even using IE or even Windows, which is foolish given that where it has a majority, IE is steadily losing market 'grip' to others such as Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: We are not taking users freedoms, the company will give a big presentto one lucky user after 30 days of their subscription. Users will sign-up first, get the activation code, install the add-in manually and he add-in will set the users homepage to the company's web site and must not change it 30 days. Also %85 of their visitors are using Internet Explorer.

Comment: All that stuff doesn't stop it from being a violation of the user's freedom.

Comment: this is a 30 days campaign; do not think that we're doing an illegal thing. We will not do it automatically without users approval, user will install it manually after subscription, accepting the eula of the campaign and he/she will be istructed about what will happens if he/she installs the add-in.

Comment: users will be instructed that changing of their homepage will be disabled for 30 days and if they change it they will be disqualified from the campaing. we're not taking their freedom, they will accept it manually what will happen.

Comment: Either way, it won't be effective, because the user can install it, then install another browser and use that for the month.

Comment: I still find stuff like this awful,  but as long as it's a clear agreement between vendor and user, I see nothing really wrong with it - consenting adults and all that...). I don't think you'll be able to actually disable changing the home page, though. Probably the best you can do is build some check that puts itself into autostart and runs frequently (yuck!)

Comment: Pekka, I believe that you might be able to set Windows' GPO/Group Policy to disable home page changes; I know that's how they do it in schools.

Comment: @Delan you're right, on second thought, there actually might be some ways. But it may take administrator rights to make the change. Oh and the joys if the uninstall routine fails 30 days later! :)

Comment: ok, we can take the disable option out but there has to be a way to detect whether the user changed to homepage. if he change his homepage the add-in will warn him that he will be disqualfied from the campaign. which registry key we have to track? Also is it possible to autostart the add-in everytime the user opens the browser?

Comment: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Start Page` is the string key you want. Again though, what's to stop the user from using another browser for the month? Also, how does this help your marketing at all? All it does is artificially pushes up your site's hits.

Comment: that's the only thing they want, push up the site hit. We're not targeting non-IE users because %85 of their visitors are using an IE browsers. What are your opinions about pulsing system (sending activation message etc.) on every the user opens the browser?

Comment: The phone-home behaviour will almost certainly set off an alarm on any good antivirus's heuristic detection, deleting your addon, and this scare would turn potential customers away from your client's site or company.

Comment: hmm... We can warn users about the antivirus detections and inform that they have to give exceptions for the add-on. I think the best way is; get the homepage information from the users once a day and send it to server, check the homepage value everytime the user opens the browser window and if it's changed warn to user to change it back to the related url.

Comment: In any case, it seems very shady and most users will turn away from your client because of this behaviour. You could act like me and Flash; just don't do it.

Comment: users will have a chance to win a car after 30 days :) so i don't think anyone who wants to win a free car will turn away from our client, this can be a good marketing option, with just setting web portal's homepage url for 30 days and wait.

Comment: I'd probably rather have a safe computer without running weird binaries than winning a car, unless I ran this addon in a virtual machine. Then again, I run Ubuntu, not Windows, so am I ineligible? What discrimination! ;)

Comment: :) they are just targeting Windows users running Internet Explorer web browser. i'm looking for a way to check if the users are using the browser actively, not like the ways you mentioned.

Comment: I already gave you the registry key for where the IE home page is stored, so what else do you need?

Comment: i found what i was looking: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/registrymonitor.aspx thank you all.

Comment: @DelanAzabani is this registry key same for all versions of Internet Explorer and Windows? Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Yes, it is the same on all versions of IE/Windows.

Comment: I think a normal, sane company wishing to do something like this would ask users to come to their website X number of times a day and just keep a record of it.  In before "they can fake it".  Well, guess what, just because you change the homepage doesn't mean jack ****.  I could set the homepage in IE and go back to using Chrome.  You'd guarantee me showing up on the webpage if you just asked me to log in twice a friggen day.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock users from changing the homepage by setting a registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Homepage
```

key type is DWORD and value is 1.

This will "grey out" the edit box in IE, but a knowledgeable user could still edit the homepage setting directly in Windows registry. Caveat: some antispyware tools raise a warning if this lock is engaged.

When you want to remove the lock, either set the value to 0 or remove the Homepage key in registry.